# Elastic search aggregation query throwing exception

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

While querying elastic search aggregate query,I'm getting "Trying to create too many buckets. Must b less than or equal to 10000 but found 10001."

How can we handle this exception?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations-bucket.html) link, the default limit of `search.max_buckets` is `10000`.

The entire point of having a limit like that is to prevent some novice user from accidentally running long time and resource consuming aggregation queries that can lead to performance issues or in worse case, crashing of ES nodes.

However, if you want to change that setting, there are two ways to go about that.

### Solution 1: Change in elasticsearch.yml (Restart of nodes Required)

You need to go to `elasticsearch.yml` of all the nodes in your cluster and add the below value in that,

`search.max_buckets = 10500`

Save the file and restart the nodes.

### Solution 1: Cluster API (No restart required)

Alternatively, I believe you can use [cluster API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html) and add the settings to the [`persistent cluster settings`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html#cluster-update-settings-api-example) as follows:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "search.max_buckets": 12000
  }
}
```

As the setting appears to be cluster wide, I would recommend `Solution 2` for this.

That being provided, do share the reasons as why you'd want the buckets to return more than 10k buckets. Also do thorough testing if you change the settings just so that you don't start seeing performance issues in live environment and if you do so, this is the first thing you'd want to keep in mind.

Let me know if this helps you resolve the issue.

Comment: @Harmeet, did the above solution resolve your issue? Do you need any further help?